# Which APK file should I upload to Firebase App Distribution?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-distribution

When I build my app with `>flutter build apk`, it creates five files:

- app-arm64-v8a-release.apk  (8.4MB)
- app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (8.1MB)
- app-release.apk (20.1MB)
- app-x86_64-release.apk (8.6MB)
- output.json (2KB)

But when I want to upload my app to Firebase App Distribution, it only asks/allows for a single APK file.

Which file should I use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to upload an `app-release.apk` as it is a universal apk which should fit for all architectures.

You have multiple apks in your output directory since flutter generates stripped apks for each architecture.